# Pandas: Matching index of one dataframe to the column of other dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have two data frames named df1 & df2:

df1

[image: df1]

df2

[image: df2]

SITE_NUMBER is set as the index of df1. Now I want to return the 'FACILITY' column of df1 if the values of 'S_STATION' of df2 matches with the index value of df1. I wrote a function for this purpose:

```
def return_facility():
   return df1[df1['SITE_NUMBER'] == pd.to_numeric(df2['S_STATION'])]['FACILITY']
```

However, the function is not working because compiler does not recognize df1['SITE_NUMBER']. Could anyone point out where I am making mistake?

Comment: `SITE_NUMBER` is the index of df1, not a column. You're referencing it like a column.

Comment: Yes agreed, is there any other way we could do matching?

Comment: @vb_rises didn't work. Throw an error message "ValueError: index must be monotonic increasing or decreasing"

Comment: `df1.sort_index().loc[:'SITE_NUMBER']`

Comment: Better solution is to use `pd.merge(df1, df2, left_index=True, right_on='S_STATION')` and then extract desired columns.

Answer (score 0):

You need `isin`. Use it on `df1.index`

```
def return_facility():
   return df1.loc[df1.index.isin(pd.to_numeric(df2['S_STATION'])), 'FACILITY']
```