# Map index of one dataframe to column of another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vlookup

I know there are [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58423707/pandas-matching-index-of-one-dataframe-to-the-column-of-other-dataframe) similar to this but they do not answer my question, so kindly bear with me.

I have 2 data frames df1 and df2.

In df1, the Order ID1 is the index and the Payment column is empty.

```
print(df1)

Order ID1    Sale Price     Payment
OD1             45            
OD2             55
OD3             56
```

In df2, the Order ID2 is the index.

```
print(df2)

Order ID2     paid value
OD1             44
OD3             41
OD2             33
```

I am trying to map the index of df1 (Order ID1) to the index of df2 (Order ID2) and return the corresponding `paid value` in the empty `payment` column. Basically I am performing a look up procedure.

I tried using the map function as follows:-

```
df2['Payment'] = df2.index.map(df1.index)
```

but I am getting the following error:

```
TypeError: 'Index' object is not callable
```

Comment: I'd suggest using `pandas.merge` to join the two DataFrames on the ID column. This would give you a new DataFrame with all three columns.

Comment: Is there a particular advantage of using merge instead of map function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are trying to map the index. You first need to create a dictionary with keys being the index of df2 and values being the paid value using `dict(zip())`. Then you can map that on `df1.index` and return it into your Payment column:

```
df1['payment'] = df1.index.map(dict(zip(df2.index,df2['paid value'])))

           Sale Price  payment
Order ID1                     
OD1                45       44
OD2                55       33
OD3                56       41
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update**: if `Order IDX` is already the index of your 2 dataframes, use simply assignment:

```
df1['Payment'] = df2['paid value']
print(df1)

# Output:
           Sale Price  Payment
Order ID1                     
OD1                45       44
OD2                55       33
OD3                56       41
```

---

**Old answer**

```
df1['Payment'] = df1['Order ID1'].map(df2.set_index('Order ID2').squeeze())
print(df1)

# Output:
  Order ID1  Sale Price  Payment
0       OD1          45       44
1       OD2          55       33
2       OD3          56       41
```